# How to get private posts only from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to obtain private posts from my profile's wall - without public ones.

With full-permission token,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/MickeySpencerShow_ID/posts
```

returns all posts - public and private.

Is there any way to filter them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with FQL, for example this query looks for private comments under given post:

```
SELECT id, post_id, parent_id, is_private 
  FROM comment
 WHERE post_id='XXXXXX' AND is_private=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to filter them, but not by using permissions.  You need to write your own code. According to the [documentation for the Posts graph object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/), there is a privacy attribute that will be set to EVERYONE, ALL_FRIENDS, NETWORKS_FRIENDS, FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS, or CUSTOM.  That should get you started.  Also, using Simon Cross' [Graph Explorer tool](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/), you can play around with different permissions and see the actual field values, without having to write code.

It seems like you are expecting permissions to filter the results.  That's not what permissions are for.  More permissions will add more data to your result set.  Default is public posts.  Getting permissions to access the private posts means that `https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts` will return the public + private posts.  Maybe you should also be looking at the documentation for the [User graph object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) to understand how permissions work.

Comment: I tried that, however if I have permission to read private posts, I also have permission to read public posts. I couldn't find combination of permissions to achive my goal.

Comment: You have to filter the results yourself.  It should be a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

forget to make query on facebook graph as if you was using SQL ... they at FB uses Cassandra that is NOSQL indeed... it happens to find on the doc that you can query for some specific "key" value , but never seen privacy 
anyway you should double check it here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/